# C# Visual Studio Reference Resolution Priority

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, monogame

I've got a TFS project with a NuGet package installed, and it references an assembly from that package. However, another copy of the same file is in a folder in the tree, and it is somehow overriding the reference and being used instead.

Even if I remove the reference entirely and manually point it to the correct path, the other file still is recognized and overrides the path.

Actual Case:

```
Correct Reference Path: 
c:\Stratigen\Stratigen\packages\MonoGame.Binaries.3.2.0\build\net40\MonoGame.Framework.dll
Overriding Reference Path: 
c:\Stratigen\Stratigen\Stratigen\Tools\MonoGame.Framework.dll
```

The file in "Tools" needs to be there  because it is a build against SharpDX (API wrapper for DirectX) and is used to compile shaders for multiple versions of MonoGame, while the game should be running against the OpenGL version (unless I were to purposefully change something).

The especially odd thing about this is that I've had this file in the "Tools" folder this entire time, and for weeks never encountered this issue, yet now it's got this odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that having included the "Tools" directory in the project was to blame. This folder is already handled by TFS but since there are a few source files in there (for the shaders) I'd included the folder. However, this for some reason gave priority to the DLLs there over those from the packages. I'm going to re-add the source files but not the DLLs/EXEs from that folder and it should work fine then.